# ctrl-c doesnt work after I use & feature in my custom shell

Tags: c, linux, shell

I'm trying to write a background feature in a custom shell I'm building.(e.g the & option like: echo hello &)

Everything works fine when I spawn forground processes, but after spwaning a background process my shell program doesn't terminate when ctrl-c is pressed.

Here is the part of my code that responsible for running the new process as background/forground:

```
struct cmd* c=parsecmd(buf);
pid_t pid;
signal(SIGTTOU,SIG_IGN);
if((pid=fork1()) == 0){
  pid=getpid();
  setpgid(pid,pid);
  if((c->type & 0x100)==0)//if forground
    tcsetpgrp(0,pid);
  signal(SIGTTOU,SIG_DFL);
  runcmd(c);
}
setpgid(pid,pid);
if((c->type & 0x100)==0){
    tcsetpgrp(0,pid);
    wait(&r);
    tcsetpgrp(0,getpgid(getpid()));
}
//printf("my pgid is %d and the forground pgid is %d\n",getpgid(getpid()),$
signal(SIGTTOU,SIG_DFL);
```

And here is what I get when I run it:

```
6.828$ echo hello &
6.828$ hello

6.828$ ^C
6.828$
```

Can someone help me figure out what is my mistake here?

Also I should say that when I use ctrl-c right after spawning the background process works. the thing that doesn't work is when I type enter and write ctrl-c and then it wont work even if I will continue spawning other commands(forground or background) .it works just fine when I type enter after spawning a forground. process(and

Comment: Terminal signals aren't sent to background processes.

Comment: What happens if you start your shell and just type Ctrl-C at the prompt, without running any command first? And what happens if you do that in any of the well-known shells (ash, ksh, bash, csh...)?

Comment: Use `kill` to signal a background process, as in (bash): `sleep 60 & kill $!`

Comment: What do you expect to happen? We don't know how you handle `CTRL+C`. When you run `echo hello &`, the background process should exit very fast. When you press `CTRL+C` after seeing the output, it is too late even if your shell really sends a signal to the background process. Try something like `sleep 60` or other long-running commands.

Comment: What I meant that ctrl-c in the shell itself doesnt work after I run a backgorund process. e.g I cant return to the bash shell.

Comment: @roycabouly, btw, generally speaking, edits should be written to make the question as clear as possible to first-time readers. For that reason, we frown on edit markers -- better to make the question read as you would write it if you were asking it with the information included from the very beginning; anyone who wants to know what changed when can click the edit-history link to get that separately.

Comment: @bishop After clarification, that is clearly not the duplicate.  The question should not be closed on that basis.

Comment: I somehow doubt that that fragment of code is sufficient, and possibly not even relevant.

Comment: Currently the misleading text remains unchanged and we only find out what you meant if we make it to the "edit" at the end.  Just edit the body to reflect accurately what you meant in the first instance.  I think your whole question can be reduced to just "After spawning a background task, my shell program no longer terminates on Ctrl+C".  A succinct re-write is often better than just adding more words if you want to clarify.

Comment: @Clifford This is the main code run in the loop that executes the commands. the parser of the command work just fine and also the code of runcmd() that runs the command.

Comment: @roycabouly :  I appreciate that, but if you don't know what the problem is you are not really in a position to know _where_ it is, and if the problem cannot be reproduced from what you have posted, it is hard to help.  With view of _all_ the code, the first thing I'd look for perhaps is whether a SIGINT handler is set-up at all.

Comment: I think I have solved it, the problem apperantly was due to a missed case in the parser. Thanks everyone for helping and sorry for this messed up question.